# Wie nennt man es, wenn man das Subjekt gewissermaßen "auslagert" und durch "es" ersetzt?

Tags: infinitive

Ein Beispielsatz:

> Es ist gut, das zu tun.

Der Infinitiv-Satz "das zu tun" wird mit einem Komma an den Hauptsatz angefügt,
und das Subjekt dessen wird "es": Wohl "es" als formales Argument (nach Wikipedia)?

Ich vermute, dass wir dann auch sagen können:

> Das zu tun, ist gut.

Und dass das Komma hier nötig ist, weil "Das zu tun" satzwertig ist.

Wie nennen wir diese Auslagerung? Es gibt doch sicher einen Fachbegriff dafür?

Lösung: Es handelt sich um ein Korrelat.

Comment: Diese Auslagerung wird als Partizipialkonstruktion bezeichnet.

Answer (score 3):

Hier kommen zwei Dinge zusammen:

**Subjektsatz**

Wenn ein ganzer Nebensatz das Subjekt des Hauptsatzes ist, nennt man das einen Subjektsatz. Wie immer kann man mit "wer oder was?" nach den Subjekt fragen, und in diesem Fall ist der ganze Nebensatz die Antwort.

> Das zu tun, ist gut.
> Was ist gut? - Das zu tun.
>
> Mich freut sehr, dass du da bist.
> Was freut mich sehr? - Dass du da bist.
>
> Wer jetzt gut aufpasst, kann am Ende etwas gewinnen.
> Wer kann am Ende etwas gewinnen? - Wer jetzt gut aufpasst.

Der Subjektsatz unterscheidet sich unter anderem dadurch von den meisten anderen Arten von Nebensätzen, dass er nicht weggelassen werden kann. Er muss unbedingt vorhanden sein, damit der Hauptsatz einen Sinn hat.

**Expletivum**

In einem Hauptatz, der kein Befehl ("Geh weg!"), kein Witz ("Treffen sich zwei Blondinen, ...") und keine Frage ist ("Bist du zuhause?") steht das Verb immer an zweiter Stelle. Manchmal möchte man aber trotzdem alle anderen Satzglieder hinter dem Verb stehen haben. Dann würde aber das Verb die Position 1 einnehmen, was nicht erlaubt ist. Um das Kunststück zu vollführen, den eigentlichen Satz mit dem Verb beginnen zu lassen, das Verb aber trotzdem an Position 2 stehen zu haben, gibt es das expletive "es".

- Ohne Expletivum, ein Satzglied steht vor dem Verb.

  > Das zu tun, ist gut.
  > Drei Bilder sind gestohlen worden.
- Mit Expletivum, alle "echten" Satzglieder stehen hinter dem Verb.

  > Es ist gut, das zu tun.
  > Es sind drei Bilder gestohlen worden.

Das Wort *es* ist hier kein Personalpronomen. Es verweist nicht auf ein Ding oder eine Person, die davor oder danach genannt wird oder wenigstens im gedachten Kontext vorhanden ist. Es ist auch nicht das Subjekt, denn nach dem Subjekt könnte man mit "wer oder was?" fragen, die Antwort darauf ist aber das tatsächliche Subjekt, also der Subjektsatz "das zu tun".

Die einzige Funktion, die ein Expletivum in einem Satz ausübt, ist die eines Lückenfüllers. Sein einziger Zweck ist, eine bestimmte Position im Satzgefüge zu besetzen.

In manchem Konstruktionen (Wenn es um das Wetter geht oder darum, dass etwas exitiert), füllt das Expletivum keine Positionslücke, sondern ersetzt das Subjekt:

> Morgen wird **es** Erdbeereis zum Dessert geben.
> Ich glaube, dass **es** bald schneit.

Comment: Bei dem **es** in den beiden Sätzen mit Nebensatz handelt es sich nicht um ein Expletivum, sondern um ein Korrelat. https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Korrelat_(Grammatik) Es ist kein reiner Platzhalter, sondern vertritt den Nebensatz.